# Get access to parent variables from child class in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have two class in Qt. In one I declared some variables and child QFrame class with QPainter. Now, if it's possible, how i can get access to parent variables from child class? 
I know that I can pass variables by signals and slots or catch child QPainter events, but i think it would be nice get access directly.

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to the visibility of the data in the base class. If the data is public or protected then you have access to it. Otherwise, the data is private and you don't have direct access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Simple example:

header parent

```
class gameWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    gameWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    int round;

};
```

class parent

```
#include "gamewindow.h"

gameWindow::gameWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
   round = 0;
}
```

header child :

```
class plArea:public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    plArea(QWidget *parent=0);

};
```

class child:

```
#include "plarea.h"

plArea::plArea(QWidget *parent):QWidget (parent)
{
    parent->round = 1;
}
```

return

> 'class QWidget' has no member named
>   'round'

Comment: here you do one thing incorrectly... you make the 'parent' variable that you pass to your child class of type QWidget, where if you were to make it of type gameWindow, it would know of round and access it with no issues

Comment: can you show me how it should looks? i include gamewindow.h to plArea header, next i do some change (http://pastebin.com/hTJ4qiKw)
and i get errror expected ')' before '*' token in line plArea(gameWindow* parent=0);